# System.TypeLoadException (WebPartsZone) in mono

Tags: .net, mono, reference, monodevelop

I load a user control in a web page which throws an exception:

```
this.LoadControl(someusercontrol); // throws TypeLoadException
```

The details :

```
System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: The classes in the module cannot be loaded.
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.Assembly:GetTypes (bool)
  at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes ()
  ... 
  in /usr/src/packages/BUILD/mono2.4.2.3/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.Compilation/BuildManager.cs:864
```

Error message:

```
 "could not load type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPartsZone from assembly 'System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0 ..."
```

I get it that WebPartsZone is not implemented in System.Web. What I do not get is why does it try to load that. **I'm not using WebParts in my webpage, or in my control**.

How can I find WHO (or WHAT) is calling/using WebPartsZone ?
 A simple "find in files" search for "webparts" returns no finds.. so what next?

Edit: I'm using ajax control toolkit 3.5 .. [MOMA](http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA)  says gives a warning about this assembly using the webparts... is it possible that asp:Panel or asp:UpdatePanel uses a webpart somewhere ? 
Last I heard,  Ajaxcontroltoolkit was working under Mono , right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran *grep -rHin webparts* in the source of the control toolkit and there are a few controls that have a `using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts` in them (MaskedEdit, TabPanel,...).

However, I just built the AjaxControlToolkit.dll assembly from those sources in mono (I'm using subversion trunk, which is quite close to the soon to be release 2.6) and it built fine. I can even run the demo with all the controls (SampleWebSite folder) without a problem... I think that some controls have the `using` for WebParts but none is actually using any type from that namespace.